# Botón no me ejecuta instrucción antes de realizar un proceso

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero que se setee el texto del boton a "Cargando..." al presionar el botón antes que se empiece a ejecutar la próxima clase pero no funciona, directamente pasa a ejecutar el TRY y después me setea el texto del botón cuando la ejecución de la clase ya terminó.
Código:

```
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton5ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jButton5.setText("Cargando...");
    try {
        MigrarDatos excel = new MigrarDatos();
        excel.LeerArchivos("C:\\JDeveloper\\mywork\\picar\\picar_app\\src\\librerias\\picar unificada.xls");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"El archivo ha sido correctamente cargado a la base de datos.","CARGA EXITOSA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        jButton5.setText("Cargar lista");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: "+e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jButton5.setText("Cargar lista");
    }
}
```

O que puedo realizar algo simple para indicarle al usuario que el archivo se está cargando por mientras que le avise

Comment: Es posible que sí se esté ejecutando solo que como tanto en el `try` como en el `catch` está la instrucción `jButton5.setText("Cargar lista")` se reemplaza por el texto "Cargar lista" inmediatamente y no ves el resultado.

Comment: No me funcionó @Mateo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un hilo para realizar el proceso, los hilos son útiles porque permiten que el flujo del programa sea divido en dos o más partes, cada una ocupándose de alguna tarea de forma independiente.

Primero instanciamos un hilo `Thread` e implementamos el método `run()` en este caso es donde va tu código, finalmente iniciamos el hilo `.start()`, cuando se ejecuta un proceso (sobre todo cuando este tarda demasiado tiempo) lo mejor es usar un hilo ya sea para mostrar un loading u otro tipo de mensajes de espera.

Con todo lo dicho tu código quedaría así:

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton5ActionPerformed
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jButton5.setText("Cargando...");
            try {
                MigrarDatos excel = new MigrarDatos();
                excel.LeerArchivos("C:\\JDeveloper\\mywork\\picar\\picar_app\\src\\librerias\\picar unificada.xls");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"El archivo ha sido correctamente cargado a la base de datos.","CARGA EXITOSA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                jButton5.setText("Cargar lista");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ERROR: "+e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                jButton5.setText("Cargar lista");
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

También es posible usar una clase extendida para esto pero para tu caso no creo que sea necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fucionó! Lo único que tuve que cambiar la referencia del JOptionPane cambiar el THIS por el JBUTTON5.

Comment: @Federico eso es porque el `this` está haciendo referencia al `Thread`. No sé en qué clase está todo ese código pero si se llama `Pepe`, puedes hacer referencia al botón mediante `Pepe.this`.